# Three equation model, supply shock that is permanent

Tags: macroeconomics

I've been stuck on an exam question regarding the three equation model and the effect of a supply shock on the model. Mostly regarding the transitional dynamics and the intuition behind it, could anyone please assist.

Consider an economy that can be described by the following two equations:

[image]

The Y is short run output

b = interest sensitivity of short-run output, m = Sensitivity of the real interest rate to inflation in a monetary policy rule, o(bar) = supply shock(Price shock to Phillips curve), a(bar) = demand shock, π= inflation rate at period t, π(bar)= Long-run inflation target in a monetary policy rule, v = Price stickiness

Note
that , , and  all represent positive parameters.
The economy is initially in a steady state.

a) Suppose that innovations in solar power permanently decrease the cost of electricity.
Analyse and explain the dynamic response of the economy to this exogenous shock.